# Use of IMPORTRANGE to juxtapose variable-length lists

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, importrange

Let's say I have two Google sheets, Doc1 and Doc2, both having only one sheet featuring two lists with the same schema, say two columns Name and Age. The lists have an unknown number of entries, but if it makes the task easier, we can assume that they have a maximum of 5 entries:

[image: Two Google sheets]

I want to collate both lists and show them in a third "Summary" document, one after the other. I can show them using these formulae, in Summary's cells `A1` and `A6`, respectively:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("1cLqgopAWG...","Sheet1!A1:B5")
=IMPORTRANGE("1564EXoW-s...","Sheet1!A1:B5")
```

However, this leaves an annoying variable number of blank lines between the two:

[image: Unwanted blank lines]

whereas I would like to show them one directly above the other, like so (values manually copied here to show what I want):

[image: What I would like to achieve]

If I try and use `IMPORTRANGE` on two contiguous rows (i.e. `A1` and `A2`), I get a `#REF!` error ("Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in A2."):

[image: #REF! error]

Is it possible to achieve what I want?
(Bonus points for removing the constraint about max number of items.)

Comment: I think I can solve this if [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/126314/using-choose-with-arrayformula-has-different-results-from-excel) worked as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- all you need to do is **`QUERY`** out empty rows:

```
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("1cLqgopAWG...", "Sheet1!A1:B5");
        IMPORTRANGE("1564EXoW-s...", "Sheet1!A1:B5")}, 
 "where Col1 is not null")
```