# Using CHOOSE with ArrayFormula has different results from Excel

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

Function `CHOOSE` within an `ArrayFormula` seems to yield different results in Google Sheets, compared to Excel. Note how only the first column is shown. Should I report it as a bug, or am I missing something?

Excel:

[image: Excel use]

Google Sheets:

[image: Google Sheets use]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- it's not clear what you are after but to mimic Excel behaviour do this:

  ```
  =CHOOSE({1;2}, {{11,22,33};{44,55,66}})
  ```

  [image: 0]

Comment: Thanks, I stripped the context from a real-life example (involving `INDIRECT` cell refs etc) to keep it as simple as possible.